# Qt C++: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt

Create a simple application in Qt (c ++) to encrypt a text. And I get the error: "Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread."

I used threads to update a text edit box in real time while entering text.

I saw other similar topics, but I did not find any solution that I could adapt to myself.

Can you please suggest me how I can solve it?

.h file

```
#ifndef GENERATORSHACODE_H
#define GENERATORSHACODE_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <thread>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class GeneratorShaCode; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class GeneratorShaCode : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GeneratorShaCode(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~GeneratorShaCode();
    QString Sha512Generator(QString);
    void updateOutputEditText();
    std::thread GenerateCode;

private:
    Ui::GeneratorShaCode *ui;
};
#endif // GENERATORSHACODE_H
```

.cpp file

```
#include "generatorshacode.h"
#include "ui_generatorshacode.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "sha512.h"
#include <string>

#include <QtDebug>

GeneratorShaCode::GeneratorShaCode(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::GeneratorShaCode)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    GenerateCode = std::thread(&GeneratorShaCode::updateOutputEditText, this);
    GenerateCode.detach();
}

GeneratorShaCode::~GeneratorShaCode()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString GeneratorShaCode::Sha512Generator(QString Qstr)
{
    return QString::fromStdString(sha512(Qstr.toStdString()));
}

void GeneratorShaCode::updateOutputEditText()
{
    while(true)
    {
       ui->textEdit_Output->setText(Sha512Generator(ui->textEdit_Input->toPlainText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly where the `"Cannot create children..."` message is coming from in this case but... you're directly accessing your `ui` data/variables simultaneously from multiple threads without any synchronization -- that's undefined behaviour (and accessing GUI components from any thread other than that on which `main` is running is unsupported by `Qt`).

Comment: You want to use signals and slots for communication between threads and the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

GUI thread is the main thread. You can't operate any ui controls directly within a sub thread. Usually you should use signals/slots between GUI thread and sub thread.

Comment: I solved it without using threads. I used slots and signals.
For the textEdit object I used the textChanged () method.

Thanks for the suggestions!